# How to create a material with variable color

Tags: unity, materials

I'm new to Unity and trying to create a [Carrom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrom) game. Since all the White and Black pieces, Queen basically have the same material and physical properties and texture except for their color, I'm trying to create a single material that I could assign to all 3 types of objects but could then set the material color per object type. Can this be achieved in Unity (I'm using 5.3.2)?

Comment: Wouldn't something like `gameobject.material.renderer.color = color.somecolor` work?

Comment: @Felsir That creates *material instances* so while they use the same *asset* the objects won't batch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`MaterialPropertyBlock`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html) probably what you are looking for.  Just make sure to create the block *once* and cache it, to save on garbage collection.

I'd create one `MaterialPropertyBlock` per piece color (so a red and a black, with the material by itself being white), cache them, and [apply the block to each piece](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.SetPropertyBlock.html) as needed.

Answer (score 2):

In a simple case you can change the main albedo color of the material of an object by assigning a different [Color](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) to

```
gameobject.renderer.material.color
```

Note that some advanced materials have multiple color properties which serve different purposes. In that case `Material.color` might not be the color you actually want to change and you have to use the [`material.SetColor(propertyName, color)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html) method.

Also, in some cases a renderer can use more than one material. In that case [`renderer.material`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html) will be the first material. When that is not the one you want to change, you can find the other materials in the [`renderer.materials`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-materials.html) array.

By the way: Changing the color of  the material of an object at runtime causes an entirely new material to be created. So when you have a large number of colored objects in your game but only a small number of different colors, it might be far more efficient to have a small number of different materials and assign these to the objects (as in Hamaz Hasan's answer) or use a MaterialPropertyBlock (as in the answer by Draco18s).

Comment: This actually creates *multiple materials* at runtime, so not technically what the asker is looking for.  Runtime material instances won't batch, which means more draw calls which for mobile devices is kind of important (I do not know the asker's requirements, but these are the downsides to utilizing this solution).

Answer (score 0):

Actually normally people get benefit and consider it as a feature of Unity. For example, in Carrom you'd probably have to have 3 colors (Black, White and Red). What you have to do is to create 3 Materials for the above colors and apply at all 3 types of object. So from that you can change a single color from material and all the objects would change their color having this material attached.

Although you can set same physical properties to all the objects.

Comment: My request to person who down-vote my answer, either post your correct answer or point me out where I am wrong. So that I'd know the wrong point. I'd consider that be a highly appreciable act.

Comment: There *is* [`MaterialPropertyBlock`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html), but I would ordinarily consider your answer correct as it's a much more direct solution.  `MaterialPropertyBlock` is better used when you want to change a material property *on a per object basis* over time.

Comment: "I'm new to Unity" I always consider the level of asker on the specific platform...

Comment: Oh, sure.  Which is why I think your answer is a good one.  "Just use multiple materials" is easy, cheap, and good for new users.